# Can an Alchemist use Two-Weapon Fighting with bombs?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

In Pathfinder, is the Alchemist class capable of using Two-Weapon Fighting with bombs?  If no, does the Fast Bombs discovery change this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Preparing and throwing a bomb is a standard action, so only one per round could be thrown.

However, the *Fast Bombs* discovery allows you to make multiple attacks per round and apply all the relevant feats, spells or abilities. This is also explicitly covered by the official [FAQ section](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9n8l).

Comment: I didn't know there was an FAQ on the product page.  Thanks.