# Are Alchemist bombs light weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

I'm currently looking at a design for a bomb-focused alchemist. I plan to use [Two-Weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat---final) (along with the Fast Bombs discovery) to get more bombs per round in mid- and late levels, and I'll possibly use the [Taddol race](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/3rd-party-races/alluria-publishing/taddol) to get Two-Weapon Fighting as a bonus feat and access to the [Innate Two-Weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/alluria-publishing/general-feats---3rd-party---alluria-publishing/innate-two-weapon-fighting) racial feat. There's been some prior discussion on bomb-heavy builds like this [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9576/bomb-based-alchemist-builds) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6875/alchemist-bomb-attacks). However, this plan hinges on bombs counting as light weapons: if they do, I get less penalty for using Two-Weapon Fighting with them (or none with the innate racial feat).

So: **Do Alchemist bombs count as light weapons, or light for the purposes of text referring to light weapons?** The fluff description of the bombs certainly makes them sound lighter/smaller than most of the weapons unambiguously defined as "light weapons", but I'm hoping to find something RAW and non-fluff to clarify the issue. I was also unable to find a definitive answer in [this similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18998/what-throwing-weapons-are-treated-as-light-weapons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an Off-the-shelf Alchemist no, this is impossible. The Bomb class feature requires a standard action to create and throw the bomb, this isn't an attack action, this is just the way the class feature works. Some have drawn comparisons to it and a Dragon's Breath Weapon.

However, if you are level 8 you may pick up the Fast Bombs discovery which then does enable you to use everything above you described. ([FAQ Link](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9n8l))

As far as them being light weapons I think that is a fair assumption, though I can't find any hard info on the topic so I'd talk to your GM about it.

Comment: I had intended the original question to imply that I was using the Fast Bombs discovery. Will edit to make this explicit.